# How to start icewm?

Tags: linux, window-manager, centos-6

I installed `icewm` 1.2.13. `Metacity` is my default window manager. Usually, to replace window manager `--replace` option is used, e.g `metacity --replace`. But my version of `icewm` does not have this option. :

```
# icewm --help
IceWM: using /root/.icewm for private configuration files
Usage: icewm [OPTIONS]
Starts the IceWM window manager.

Options:
  --display=NAME      NAME of the X server to use.
  --client-id=ID      Client id to use when contacting session manager.
  --sync              Synchronize X11 commands.

  -c, --config=FILE   Load preferences from FILE.
  -t, --theme=FILE    Load theme from FILE.
  -x, --cursor=[small|medium|large|huge]  cursor size.
  -n, --no-configure  Ignore preferences file.

  -v, --version       Prints version information and exits.
  -h, --help          Prints this usage screen and exits.
  --restart           Don't use this: It's an internal flag.

Environment variables:
  ICEWM_PRIVCFG=PATH  Directory to use for user private configuration files,
                      "$HOME/.icewm/" by default.
  DISPLAY=NAME        Name of the X server to use, depends on Xlib by default.
  MAIL=URL            Location of your mailbox. If the schema is omitted
                      the local "file" schema is assumed.

Visit http://www.icewm.org/ for report bugs, support requests, comments...
```

When I try to start `icewm` I get this message:

```
# icewm
IceWM: using /root/.icewm for private configuration files
IceWM: xinerama: heads=1
IceWM: xinerama: 0 +0+0 1680x1050
IceWM: xinerama: heads=1
IceWM: xinerama: 0 +0+0 1680x1050
IceWM: Another window manager already running, exiting...
```

How to start `icewm`?

(I use Centos 6.5)

**===EDIT===**

Start with `--replace` option gives the same result:

```
# icewm --replace
IceWM: using /root/.icewm for private configuration files
IceWM: xinerama: heads=1
IceWM: xinerama: 0 +0+0 1680x1050
IceWM: xinerama: heads=1
IceWM: xinerama: 0 +0+0 1680x1050
IceWM: Another window manager already running, exiting...
```

**===EDIT===**

I found some solution but it uncomfortable. I changed system `runlevel` to 3. This disable graphical mode. When I am in text mode I command:

```
# which icewm
/path
# xinit -e /path
```

`xterm` is needed to run it.

Is there a better solution? I would like to simply replace window manager.

**=====EDIT====**
My linux release:

```
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
Release:    6.5
Codename:   Final
```

Comment: Please provide more details: Login manager, which distribution, ...—what keeps you from simply starting an IceWM session? I’m pretty sure it’s already available when logging in.

Comment: I think you should have a look at ~/.xinitrc and startx command.

Comment: @user236012 I have not get ~/.xinitrc file.

Comment: @DanielB I added my linux release to my question. What you mean by "what keeps you from simply starting an IceWM session?"? I wrote result of icewm command in my question. In display manager I can only choose GNOME and User script.

Comment: @Mariusz I’m currently on vacation, so you’ll have to wait another week. Could you please list which IceWM-related packages are installed? Generally, one should have placed a file in `/usr/share/xsessions` (ore similar). This is where GDM gets its list from.

Comment: `gnome.desktop` and `xinit-compat.desktop` files are in `/usr/share/xsessions`. I installed IceWm from sources so I suppose that it is not added to X start scripts. So I suppose that I have not got any IceWM related packages.

Answer (score 0):

All I can say is that `icewm-session` is the recommended way to start IceWM.  It is also work in progress...  So far I can start it using `$ startx icewm-session`, yet my global X settings are override by IceWM defaults, and an virtual terminal is opened by default once the IceWM session is up.  To close the session I have to press Ctrl+C in that terminal, otherwise, it stays...

Enjoy! ;)